# how to add images side by side word document using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to add images side by side in my word document using apache poi. I tried to make it table method and I wrote this codes for it.

```
XWPFTable imgTable;
            XWPFTableRow rows=null;
            XWPFTableCell cells=null;
            imgTable=document.createTable(20,2);
            imgTable.getCTTbl().getTblPr().unsetTblBorders();
            rows=imgTable.getRow(1);
            cells=rows.getCell(0);
            XWPFParagraph imgPara = document.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun img = imgPara.createRun();
            for(int z=0;z<imgPaths.size();z++)
            {

                if(imgPaths.get(z).contains("-"))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(imgPaths.get(z));
                    try {
                        is2 = new FileInputStream(imgPaths.get(z));
                        is3=new FileInputStream(imgPaths.get(z+1));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        img.addPicture(is2, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "", Units.toEMU(450), Units.toEMU(200));
                    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

The file paths in my imgPaths arraylist which is loading data came from access database. In my database, there are some file paths. If there aren't file path, I'm putting **-** this in my database cell. For example I have 20 cells for image paths but I added 7 file path so I'm putting this **-** the remaining 13. So, when i am running the codes there is no error but images not seen the word document. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `XWPFParagraph imgPara` and `XWPFRun img` are not inside the table. They are outside the table instead.

Also your code adds all pictures into the same `XWPFRun`. But it should add the pictures into different runs which are in `XWPFTableCell`s. To do so you need to get the first paragraph of the `XWPFTableCell` and then the first text run in that paragraph.

The following complete code shows how this could be done. It uses pictures from public accessible internet  resources. So it can be used without having picture files stored locally.

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class CreateWordPicturesInTable {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  List<String> pictureURLs = new ArrayList<String>();
  pictureURLs.add("https://www.eastcottvets.co.uk/uploads/Animals/gingerkitten.jpg");
  pictureURLs.add("https://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/A-kitten-meowing.jpg");
  pictureURLs.add("-");
  pictureURLs.add("https://www.animalfriends.co.uk/app/uploads/2014/08/06110347/Kitten-small.jpg");
  pictureURLs.add("https://d27ucmmhxk51xv.cloudfront.net/media/english/illustration/kitten.jpg");
  pictureURLs.add("-");
  pictureURLs.add("-");

  int picturesCount = pictureURLs.size();
  int tableRows = (int)Math.round(picturesCount/2d);

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("The kitten pictures: ");

  XWPFTable imgTable = document.createTable(tableRows,2);
  XWPFTableCell cell;

  URL url;
  BufferedImage image;
  Dimension dim;
  ByteArrayOutputStream bout;
  ByteArrayInputStream bin;
  int tableRow = 0;
  int tableCell = 0;
  for (String pictureURL : pictureURLs) {
   cell = imgTable.getRow(tableRow).getCell(tableCell++);
   if (tableCell == 2) {
    tableCell = 0;
    tableRow++;
   }

   if (!"-".equals(pictureURL)) {
    url = new URL(pictureURL);
    image = ImageIO.read(url);
    dim = new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    double width = dim.getWidth();
    double height = dim.getHeight();
    double scaling = 1.0;
    if (width > 72*3) scaling = (72*3)/width; //scale width not to be greater than 3 inches
    bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", bout);
    bout.flush();
    bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(bout.toByteArray());

    if (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) paragraph = cell.getParagraphs().get(0); else paragraph = cell.addParagraph();
    if (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) run = paragraph.getRuns().get(0); else run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.addPicture(bin, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "kitten", 
     Units.toEMU(width*scaling), Units.toEMU(height*scaling));

    //lock aspect ratio
    run.getCTR().getDrawingArray(0).getInlineArray(0).addNewCNvGraphicFramePr().addNewGraphicFrameLocks().setNoChangeAspect(true);
   }
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordPicturesInTable.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: I tried this codes, it gives me this error **java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: \\ptrisf02\group\Corrolog\EVM\Pictures\EV12080-01\DSCF7270.JPG**.

Comment: @mustafa53: My code is complete and works as it is. It uses `HTTP` or `HTTPS` resources as picture resources. If you are using file resources rather than `HTTP` or `HTTPS` as picture resources, then you need using `FileInputStream` instead of `URL`s. But that you had done already in your showed code in your question.

Comment: OK. I used FileInputSteam and it worked. There is some speed issues but it's enough for now. Thanks.